# Adding progress bar to page

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular7, angular8

I am trying to make progress bar in angular. I started using angular mmat-stepper and my code is as follows::

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material'
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my html page::

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear] = "isLinear" #stepper>
   <mat-step [stepControl] = "firstFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup] = "firstFormGroup">
         <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter your name</ng-template>
         <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder = "Last name, First name" formControlName = "firstCtrl" required>
         </mat-form-field>
         <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step [stepControl] = "secondFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup] = "secondFormGroup">
         <ng-template matStepLabel>Enter your address</ng-template>
         <mat-form-field>
           <input matInput placeholder = "Address" formControlName = "secondCtrl" required>
         </mat-form-field>
         <div>
           <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
           <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
         </div>
      </form>
   </mat-step>
   <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
         Details taken.
      <div>
         <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
         <button mat-button (click) = "stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
   </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

My component is as follows::

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Validators } from "@angular/forms";
export interface Food {
   value: string;
   display: string;
}
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'materialApp';   
   firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
   secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
   constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
   ngOnInit() {
      this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
         firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
      });
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
         secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
      });
   }
}
```

The output I am getting is something like this::

[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxXUl.png)

Desired output::

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMISG.jpg)

By using folowwing CSS ::

```
.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I am able to get following progress bar ::

[css_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okBut.png)

But I am not getting those bigger size blue color tilted triangle. How can i get progress bar same as in my desired output image?

Answer (score 0):

If you want create your own stepper, with your design, i recommend you create from Material CDK Stepper (https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/overview), you can change everything, pass any constants, aliases, and other things, i don't know if is really what you want, but i hope i have helped you... But if you searching how create a progress bar, has in material angular website (https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) is really good too!